# SNAT port exhaustion caused by server-side rendering of Angular app on Azure App Service

Tags: node.js, azure, asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service, angular-universal

I have an app built using the ASP.NET Core Angular spa template (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/angular) with server-side rendering (SSR) enabled. The app is deployed to an Azure App Service.

Everything works fine until the app receives a large number of requests (~ 1000) in a short period. At that point, the number of outbound connections from the app service increases dramatically and SNAT port exhaustion occurs. After some troubleshooting, it appears that the source of the increase in outbound connections is the node service making calls back to the app itself to perform SSR.

The details of performing SSR are handled inside the ASP.NET Core pre-rendering logic, so I'm not sure how to make it reuse http connections and/or how to configure keepalive on the node service.

Does anyone know how to force the reuse of http connections when performing SSR with ASP.NET Core? Seems like there must be a way to do this or it would be impossible to scale any app that uses SSR.

Comment: Does your angular app send HTTP requests, also during SSR back to your web api? Plesk doesn't even allow this, so I was bound to use the SupplyData delegate. Perhaps this could solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a chance to review our [recommended practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-intermittent-outbound-connection-errors#avoiding-the-problem) to avoid port exhaustion?

If you do not think you're able to easily implement connection pooling for your connections and the calls, and the calls are going from one Azure Web App back into the same web app, I might suggest you look into the service endpoint recommendation. This would allow you to avoid the limits in place.

In the meantime, as a quick fix, you can scale up your app to a larger size (S1 to S2 for example) as the larger sizes provide you with more outbound connections.